# How to get formatting of styles in Word document in officer?

Tags: r, fonts, officer

I want to write some documents with `officer` and I have some predefined styles in my word document that I load with `read_docx()`. Now I can look at the styles but I especially want to know which font type or which font size each style has and I cannot find that.
This is all I can find:

```
Document <- read_docx(FILEPATH)
head(Document$styles)
  style_type style_id style_name is_custom is_default
1  paragraph   Normal     Normal     FALSE       TRUE
2  paragraph Heading1  heading 1     FALSE      FALSE
3  paragraph Heading2  heading 2     FALSE      FALSE
4  paragraph Heading3  heading 3     FALSE      FALSE
5  paragraph Heading4  heading 4     FALSE      FALSE
6  paragraph Heading5  heading 5     FALSE      FALSE
```

Unfortunately there is no column with the font size or font type.
I really need to have the font size (for example 10) and font type (for example "Times New Roman") of heading 1 in `R` because the argument `style` of the function `body_add_par` is not enough for my purposes. Is there a way to get this?

Edit: It also would be great if the solution is not from `officer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do this in officer. In fact, in the end I had to parse the xml contents of the docx to get the fonts.

It turns out that not all styles have a font set. Some inherit from other styles, and some just take the default value given by Word. Anyway, parsing the xml is pretty involved, so this is a bit involved / messy.

First you need to unzip the docx to get its style xml. If you have `officer` you will also have the required `zip` package, so we'll use this:

```r
library(zip)
doc_path <- "my_file_path.docx"
unzip(doc_path, files = "word/styles.xml", exdir = path.expand("~/"))
```

Now we need to parse the xml:

---

### Edit

As pointed out in the comments by @TobiSonne, the `sz` values are in half points, not points, so we need to half them to get the fonts' point sizes.

---

```r
read_xml(path.expand("~/word/styles.xml")) %>%
xml_nodes(xpath = "//w:style")             %>%
lapply(xml_new_root)                       %>%
lapply(function(x) data.frame(
  name = x %>% xml_node(xpath = "//w:name") %>% xml_attr("val"),
  based_on = x %>% xml_node(xpath = "//w:basedOn") %>% xml_attr("val"),
  font = x %>% xml_node(xpath = "//w:rFonts") %>% xml_attr("ascii"),
  size = x %>% xml_node(xpath = "//w:sz") %>% xml_attr("val") %>% as.numeric() %>% `/`(2),
  stringsAsFactors = F)) %>%
{do.call("rbind", .)} -> font_table
```

This gives us the font table, but there are lots of missing values to infer from inheritance etc:

```r
read_xml(path.expand("~/word/styles.xml")) %>%
xml_node(xpath = "//w:docDefaults//w:rPr") %>% 
xml_new_root -> defaults

default_size <- xml_node(defaults, xpath = "//w:sz") %>% 
                xml_attr("val") %>%
                as.numeric() %>%
                `/`(2)
default_font <- xml_node(defaults, xpath = "//w:rFonts") %>% xml_attr("ascii")
if(is.na(default_font))
  default_font <- xml_node(defaults, xpath = "//w:rFonts") %>% xml_attr("asciiTheme")

font_table$size[is.na(font_table$size) & is.na(font_table$based_on)] <- default_size
font_table$font[is.na(font_table$font)] <- default_font
font_table$based_on[is.na(font_table$based_on)] <- "default"
```

Now we have:

```r
font_table
#>                      name             based_on            font size
#> 1                  Normal              default      minorHAnsi   12
#> 2               heading 2               Normal      minorHAnsi   13
#> 3  Default Paragraph Font              default      minorHAnsi   12
#> 4            Normal Table              default      minorHAnsi   12
#> 5                 No List              default      minorHAnsi   12
#> 6              Table Grid          TableNormal      minorHAnsi <NA>
#> 7          List Paragraph               Normal      minorHAnsi <NA>
#> 8            Normal (Web)               Normal Times New Roman <NA>
#> 9            Balloon Text               Normal          Tahoma    8
#> 10      Balloon Text Char DefaultParagraphFont          Tahoma    8
#> 11         Heading 2 Char DefaultParagraphFont      minorHAnsi   13
```

Comment: I tested it now, it works great, but do you have an idea why every font size is 10 greater than I would expect? In my document I would expect for default 12 but I get the result 22 (and in the raw xml it actually IS 22).

Comment: I couldn't figure that one out either @TobiSonne. My understanding is that the default font and size are implementation defined, but I was unable to confirm this from a brief search on the topic.

Comment: OK, thank you! You also had that "problem" with the font size?

Comment: It seems that minorHAnsi is a synonym for "whatever font is labelled as minorFont in the xml files in the word/themes subfolder". You could parse this xml to get the default minor font and insert it into the table. I'm not sure about the default font size. I can't find that in the xml.

Comment: I've found an explanation: It is in half-points. Default is not 12 but 11, half of 22. See here: http://officeopenxml.com/WPtextFormatting.php

Comment: @TobiSonne that makes more sense. Thanks for letting me know. I'll update the answer to reflect this

Comment: thanks a bunch didn't realize sz is in half points in the xml

Comment: Good to know. Is there a way to set style parameters within `officer`, or does all the text styling have to be done within ftext() ?